# REST API ROUTE PATHS - best practice for authenticated resource?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api

I have an API built with Laravel that works with authentication tokens (the passport package). It is unclear to me what should be the best practice for resources that are accessed within an authenticated session.

Let me explain.

Let's say I would like to see the orders of a user as an administrator, I visit: `/v1/users/5/orders` and all orders get listed for user with ID 5.

But now the user with ID 5 is authenticated. What should the URL be to access his own orders resource?

Would that be: `/v1/users/5/orders` (and check if it's either an admin or the session belongs to the user with ID of 5)

OR `/v1/my/orders`

OR `/v1/my-orders`

OR `/v1/orders` (and use session ID of user 5, - OR list all results when admin)

It just gets confusing when on the same URL the orders can be listed because an admin wants to access it. Or it is actually the session user that wants to see them.

Comment: You can add `/me` as a short cut for `/users/:id`. So if you're logged in as user with id `123` and call `/me/orders`, it would be the same endpoint as: `/user/123/orders`. And if you're logged in as `123` and try and access `/users/234/orders`, you would get access denied. And when you're logged in as admin, you can access all.

Comment: There isn't really any "best practice" for this though. Just do it in a way that makes sense for you and your application. The most important thing is to be consistent and to document it properly.

Comment: I would stick with `/v1/users/{userId}/orders` for "...access his own orders resource..." and `/v1/orders` for general purpose order fetching (e.g. pagination) but definitely no prefixes like `/me`, `myself` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `/v1/orders`, that will display a collection of orders based on privileges:
- all orders in case of an admin session
- orders belonging to the authenticated user, in case of a less privileged user.

Adding a prefix like `/my/orders` or `my-orders` does not bring any value.

For the sub-collections I would keep the route `/v1/users/5/orders` that will allow admin to access user orders.

This is a pretty good tutorial that explains API resource naming: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Comment: So far I implemented exactly this approach. So yes, I agree. But I do think /my/ or my-order DOES bring a little bit of value. Because you separate some logic. But i'm not certain if that is worth the trouble of creating separate actions.